# Please undelete this answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4184452/352552)

Yes, it was snarky.  Yes, it wasn't *really* an answer, but, as the comments have noted, it's the best answer of the bunch (as evidenced by the 100+ upvotes it has).

Moreover, it's the only answer that states—if in a snarky, circuitous way—the fundamental problem with the original question: OP's code is dominated much more by the IO than with the speed of the respective languages.

**EDIT**

I'd just like to also point out that, as `@thirtydot` says, whatever problems this answer suffers from are more than made up for with the comments beneath it.

Comment: At the very least, convert it to a comment. And then let us massively upvote it.

Comment: @Anthony - I really think it needs to be an answer at the very top (well, second in line) for visitors to see, not buried in the comment pile.

Comment: I don't disagree. If anything, just a minor addition entailing what your third paragraph says is all that's needed to clarify the point for those who do not find it obvious.

Comment: @Anthony - agree.  A little edit and the votes would comport with SO's newer, stricter standards.

Comment: Why undelete that answer when you should delete the whole question!

Comment: If the answer was edited to add the clarification, I would perhaps agree. The problem is, IMO, that if someone does not already know that, and therefore is asking/wondering that question, what is there now will simply seem to be an insult. Adding, after the snarky part, a clear explanation would at least make it an answer. Although, one I personally would still not upvote as 'Helpful'. That said... I think the *question* is bad to start with...

Comment: @six - sigh, I hope this meta post doesn't result in the whole question being wiped.  There's a lot for future visitors to learn from seeing other people's bad ideas / bad questions, and I think this is a good example.

Comment: It's funny and true. Undelete it! The comments more than make up for the succinct answer.

Comment: "There's a lot for future visitors to learn from seeing other people's bad ideas / bad questions". This might explain a lot of the arguments I see on meta

Comment: @AdamRackis: Why deal with the, *"but this question is still here!"* There are plenty of better, "why is my performance like this?" questions.

Comment: **DELETED.**  Will just finished undeleting the answer, though.

Comment: I find it funny that this discussion essentially resulted in nine more people downvoting the question. In regards to what @sixlettervariables said, I also support Adam's point about leaving the question in place -- the OP is asking an innocuous (if poorly-worded) question and is ignorant about an absolutely **crucial** point of software development. I read this question when I became an active member here, and the "aha!" moment of reading Timbo's answer was invaluable.

Comment: @jwiscarson - I knew some downvotes would come to OP when I posted, so I threw him a +1 to try to compensate. Also, it looks like the answer in question has also received 17 upvotes today!

Comment: @AdamRackis, not a bad thought (re: the question itself). I hadn't upvoted that answer before because it was so short, but Will's edit made it so much better, and so warranted the upvote today.

Comment: @jwiscarson: if the question is worth asking, it'll get asked again. Hopefully this time without so many snarky comments pretending to be answers. Otherwise, it'll get closed and deleted again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a little conversation amongst moderators, I edited the answer to move a couple of the good comments into it.  Its now undeleted.

Comment: Thanks Will.  Stack Overflow is now a slightly better place thanks to you :)

Comment: .. and now the whole thing is vaporized with no mechanism for us serfs to vote to undelete. :(

Comment: No good deed goes unpunished.

Comment: Will - did OP flag his question asking for it to be deleted?  Is that why Shog killed it?

Comment: @AdamRackis: That's a good question for Shiggety.  I have no idea; it all happened after I debooked the area.

Comment: Might be a good question for the moderator-only chat.  Pity that after all that it's just nuked

Comment: @AdamRackis: I guess some folk are unhappy with the quality of the question, and that not enough people cared to vote to reopen (it was closed for a year or so before this).   Now its generating more noise than signal, and when that happens things tend to be deleted.